# Display Base64 image string in MS Access Report/Form

Tags: ms-access, base64, bitmapdata

I have a Client that is using MS Access, I need to be able to convert a Base64 String representation of a Bitmap image, so that it can be displayed in an MS Access Report.

I know how to do this is C# etc, but don't know where to start with Access...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution may be to use an external program:

- make your own in C# as you know how to do
- if you just want to display it you can do it with the user's browser

Comment: I am not very familiar with Access reports, I assume that they can use some form of VBA Macro to convert the encoded string to the original image.

Comment: Can a Access report make a call to an external piece of C# code? That seems like the best option but I am restricted by what Access can do.

Comment: I guess you could simply run a compiled executable?